# I need help proving this problem using the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image]

I only need help with part (a). I figure once I get that, part (b) should be easy.

Anyway, I know I'm supposed to let $h$ be a function $h(t) = f(t) - g(t)$, and use the IVT from this point to solve. But how do I do that in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inclination to make the function $h(t) = f(t) - g(t)$ is correct. We want to prove that there exists some $x$ in the unit interval such that $f(x) = g(x)$, which is equivalent to saying $h(x)=0$. The key realization here is that $h(0) = f(0)-g(0) = -1$ and $h(1) = f(1)-g(1) = 1$, so by IVT, $h$ must be zero somewhere in between (given that you know that the difference of two continuous functions is indeed continuous and that the IVT works).

Part b just involves shifting and scaling the interval, but take care because the hikers leave at different times (the functions $f$ and $g$ are not initially defined across the same intervals).

Comment: My question is: Is $x\in [0,1]$ or $x\in (0,1)$ ? The first one is not holding to be true it seems

Comment: Both work. Why do you say otherwise?

Comment: Just because f(0) =1, g(0)=0 hence $f(x)\neq g(x)$ if $x=0$ . Similarly $f(x)\neq g(x)$ if $x=1$. Am I missing something please?